# ViewPager inside ScrollView inside SwipeRefreshLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-scrollview, swiperefreshlayout

I have a layout which includes a SwipeRefreshLayout, a ScrollView and a ViewPager.

The SwipeRefreshLayout is used to refresh the ViewPager and the ScrollView is because the ViewPager can have content that don't fits on display.

When I try to scroll down nothing happens but I can see there is more content to show. When I scroll up the SwipeRefresh is invoked.

My XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    style="@style/TabLayout"
    android:paddingEnd="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingStart="16dp" />

<com.gmail.bathingrad.school.widget.SwipeRefreshView
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.gmail.bathingrad.school.widget.SwipeRefreshView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Screenshot of how it look like (the last purple box is outside of display):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlrdz.png

Edit:
After some research I have found out that the problem is because of the fact that the ScrollView don't know the height of the largest item in the ViewPager. I'm searching for a way to change the height of the ViewPager dynamically.

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/11/tabs-with-swipe-views/#more-79

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking, writing and testing I have found a solution that works. 
I put a extended ScrollView in every page of the ViewPager and then in the ScrollView I added a constructor with Context and SwipeRefreshLayout.

I overridden the method onScrollChanged and checked if the ScrollView was scrolled to the top. If it was not, I disabled the SwipeRefreshLayout.

```
<com.gmail.bathingrad.school.widget.SwipeRefreshView
    android:id="@+id/refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</com.gmail.bathingrad.school.widget.SwipeRefreshView>
```

ScrollView.class:

```
public class ScrollView extends android.widget.ScrollView {

    SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh;

    public ScrollView(Context context, SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh) {
        super(context);

        this.swipeRefresh = swipeRefresh;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onScrollChanged(int l, int t, int oldl, int oldt) {
        super.onScrollChanged(l, t, oldl, oldt);

        Log.i("School", "T: " + t);

        if (t != 0) {
            swipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
        } else if (t == 0) {
            swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

ViewPagerAdapter instantiateItem method:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        LinearLayout[] schemeLayout = readScheme.generateScheme();
        ScrollView[] scrollView = new ScrollView[5];

        // SwipeRefreshLayout
        SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) container.getParent();

        swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);

        scrollView[position] = new ScrollView(context, swipeRefresh);

        scrollView[position].addView(schemeLayout[position]);

        container.addView(scrollView[position]);

        return scrollView[position];
}
```

This works!

The reason why I call `swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);` is because of the problem that when the user scrolls down and then swipes to another page the swipeRefresh was disabled.

Hope someone will find this usefull

Answer (score -2):

Google resolve this issue with an example posted on the google-sample github projet.

Create a view that extends the original SwipeRefreshLayout :

```
/*
 * Copyright 2014 The Android Open Source Project
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *       http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.example.android.swiperefreshmultipleviews;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AbsListView;

/**
 * A descendant of {@link android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout} which supports multiple
 * child views triggering a refresh gesture. You set the views which can trigger the gesture via
 * {@link #setSwipeableChildren(int...)}, providing it the child ids.
 */
public class MultiSwipeRefreshLayout extends SwipeRefreshLayout {

    private View[] mSwipeableChildren;

    public MultiSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MultiSwipeRefreshLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    /**
     * Set the children which can trigger a refresh by swiping down when they are visible. These
     * views need to be a descendant of this view.
     */
    public void setSwipeableChildren(final int... ids) {
        assert ids != null;

        // Iterate through the ids and find the Views
        mSwipeableChildren = new View[ids.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
            mSwipeableChildren[i] = findViewById(ids[i]);
        }
    }

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(can_child_scroll_up)
    /**
     * This method controls when the swipe-to-refresh gesture is triggered. By returning false here
     * we are signifying that the view is in a state where a refresh gesture can start.
     *
     * <p>As {@link android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout} only supports one direct child by
     * default, we need to manually iterate through our swipeable children to see if any are in a
     * state to trigger the gesture. If so we return false to start the gesture.
     */
    @Override
    public boolean canChildScrollUp() {
        if (mSwipeableChildren != null && mSwipeableChildren.length > 0) {
            // Iterate through the scrollable children and check if any of them can not scroll up
            for (View view : mSwipeableChildren) {
                if (view != null && view.isShown() && !canViewScrollUp(view)) {
                    // If the view is shown, and can not scroll upwards, return false and start the
                    // gesture.
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(can_child_scroll_up)

    // BEGIN_INCLUDE(can_view_scroll_up)
    /**
     * Utility method to check whether a {@link View} can scroll up from it's current position.
     * Handles platform version differences, providing backwards compatible functionality where
     * needed.
     */
    private static boolean canViewScrollUp(View view) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 14) {
            // For ICS and above we can call canScrollVertically() to determine this
            return ViewCompat.canScrollVertically(view, -1);
        } else {
            if (view instanceof AbsListView) {
                // Pre-ICS we need to manually check the first visible item and the child view's top
                // value
                final AbsListView listView = (AbsListView) view;
                return listView.getChildCount() > 0 &&
                        (listView.getFirstVisiblePosition() > 0
                                || listView.getChildAt(0).getTop() < listView.getPaddingTop());
            } else {
                // For all other view types we just check the getScrollY() value
                return view.getScrollY() > 0;
            }
        }
    }
    // END_INCLUDE(can_view_scroll_up)
}
```

Use this view in your xml layout :

```
<com.example.android.swiperefreshmultipleviews.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/swiperefresh"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- your code -->

</com.example.android.swiperefreshmultipleviews.MultiSwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And in your activity or fragment, you can use this component with :

```
mSwipeRefreshLayout = (MultiSwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swiperefresh);
mSwipeRefreshLayout.setSwipeableChildren(android.R.id.list, android.R.id.empty);
```

android.R.id.list and android.R.id.empty is the ids for your list or recycler view. The view work perfectly with two list with same ids.

You can see real example at the [google-sample github project](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-SwipeRefreshMultipleViews).