# How to manage PullToRefreshLayout when screeh is scrollable?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, pull-to-refresh

I am using `PullToRefreshLayout` in my `Xamarin` forms app. It is working fine when screen is not scrollable. But if screen is scrollable and user scroll to bottom and then again try to scroll up then it doesn't scroll up and `PullToRefreshLayout` starts. 
I want that `PullToRefreshLayout` works only if screen is at top and can not scroll up. If user at bottom of screen and trying to scroll up then he can simply scroll the screen until he reach at top. After that `PullToRefreshLayout` can call. 
How I can manage it?

```
   <controls:PullToRefreshLayout x:Name="pRefreshApps" BackgroundColor="Transparent"  IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy}" IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True" RefreshColor="Blue">
  <Grid>
    <WebView x:Name="hubWebView" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
    <StackLayout WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Padding="0,10,10,0">
    <Image x:Name="imgCross" IsVisible="False" WidthRequest="40" HeightRequest="40" VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="EndAndExpand" Source="WhiteTickGreyBackground.png"/>
    </StackLayout>
    <Grid x:Name="loaderGrid" IsVisible="{Binding CommonViewModel.IsLoading}">
      <Grid BackgroundColor="#000000" Opacity="0.4" />
      <local:CustomProgressBar x:Name="myProgressBar" VerticalOptions="Start" BackgroundColor="Transparent" IsEnabled="{Binding CommonViewModel.IsLoading}"  IsVisible="{Binding CommonViewModel.IsLoading}"/>
    </Grid>
  </Grid>
</controls:PullToRefreshLayout>
```

Comment: Please include sample source code

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31618647/viewpager-inside-scrollview-inside-swiperefreshlayout). It might help

Comment: I have added the xaml code.

Comment: Is the `PullToRefreshLayout` nested within the scroll view?

Comment: No, I didn't use any scroll layout. But if there will lot of items, it will scroll automatically.